# Max aggregate function in hive

Tags: sql, hive

My current table is as follows:

```
ID    EventID    Time               Count
1     ABC        1435205220000      5
1     ABC        1500205220000      3
2     DEF        1435205220000      4
```

Output:

```
ID    EventID    Time               Count
1     ABC        1435205220000      5
2     DEF        1435205220000      4
```

Currently, I `Group by` ID, EventID to get `max`(Count). However, I need Time in the output as well, but if I add Time to Group By column then I wont get the desired output.

Comment: you can do a `max(time)`. this way you will always get the time in your output. This is assuming the counts are unique for a particular time.

Comment: They might not be unique.

Comment: please include you current query and add more data from your table.

Comment: `select id, eventid, max(time), max(count) from tablename group by id, eventid`..try this

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

I would suggest that you update the version of Hive.  An alternative is something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select id, max(count) as maxc
      from table t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id;
```

This will return duplicate rows if an id has two with the same max count.  (You can get the same effect in the first query by using `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Do, I need to upgrade hive to 0.11? Is there a way I can do it in hive 0.9?